# Error when tuning xgboost model in caret's train function in parallel

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost, doparallel

I am trying to run some cross validation tuning in caret for an xgboost model. I have a large tuning grid so I'd like to run it in parallel. I set up the data as a sparse matrix, set up the tuning grid, the parallel processing, and then try to run `train`, however I receive a connection error each time. If I disable the parallel options it will run just fine. It's not my data because both this sample data and my actual data have the same problem. What could be causing it? I am also curious why I need to define the y label in the `train` function, when the xgb.Dmatrix `dtrain` already has a pointer to it.

The example data is in the DALEX package, the apartments dataset.

```
library(caret)
library(xgboost)
library(Matrix)
library(DALEX) # get access to the sample data called "apartments"
library(doParallel)

x.train <- sparse.model.matrix(m2.price ~. -1 , data = apartments)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(x.train, label = apartments$m2.price)

grid = expand.grid(
  nrounds = 500,
  eta = seq(.002,0.004,by = .002),
  max_depth = seq(2, 4, by = 2),
  gamma = 0, 
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = seq(8, 10, by = 2),
  subsample = 0.5
)

# set cross validation
fitControl = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5
)

# set up parallel processing
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()


Tune = train(x = dtrain, y = apartments$m2.price,
             trControl = fitControl,
             tuneGrid = grid,
             method = "xgbTree",
             na.action = na.pass
)

Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

Comment: Sorry, it is in the DALEX package. The apartments dataset. I'll edit the question to state this.